# Feynman-Kac theorem: probabilistic proof of existence of solution to parabolic PDE

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, linear-pde

Friedman (in his book: PDEs of Parabolic Type) shows how to construct a solution to the Cauchy problem
$$
\partial_t u(t,x) = b(x) \partial_x u(t,x) + \frac{1}{2} \sigma(x)^2 \partial_{x,x} u(t,x)
$$
with initial condition $u(0,x) = f(x)$ using the parametrix method (no probability involved) under the conditions: $b, \sigma, f$ are $\alpha$-Holder continuous. In particular, $u \in C^{1,2}$.

It is also well-know by the Feynman-Kac theorem that if $u$ has polynomial growth, then it has a  stochastic representation as $u(t,x) = \mathbb{E}[f(X_t^x)]$, where $X$ solves the SDE
$$
X_t^x = x + \int_0^t b(X_s^x) \, ds + \int_0^t \sigma(X_s^x) \, dB_s .
$$

As Friedman shows (in another book: SDEs and Applications), one can ***define*** $v(t,x) := \mathbb{E}[f(X_t^x)]$ and prove directly that $v \in C^{1,2}$ and it solves the above PDE when the following conditions are satisfied: $b, \sigma, f$ are all twice continuously differentiable with bounded derivatives.

My questions:

**(1): Why do we make different assumptions about the regularity of $b, \sigma, f$ in each case?**

**(2): Can one define $v(t,x) := \mathbb{E}[f(X_t^x)]$ and, under the assumptions $b, \sigma, f$ are $\alpha$-Holder continuous (possibly also need linear growth), prove that $v$ solves the PDE?**

Comment: of course $b,σ,f$ are all twice continuously differentiable ! see : http://www1.se.cuhk.edu.hk/~seem5670/lecturenotes/Lecture5.pdf if $b,σ,f$ are not twice differentiable, how to define the stochastic diﬀerential equation ? $dX_{t}=\beta(t,X_{t})du+\gamma(t,X_{t})dW_{t}$ if we can not define the stochastic equation, how to transform it to Cauchy problem ? if you want to use the holder condition to study this stochastic diﬀerential equation, i suggest this paper : http://www.math.ucla.edu/~samxu/FeynmanKac.pdf is it helpful ? thank you !

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question being asked.

Comment: Just for clarity:

You certainly do not need $b, \sigma$ to be $C^2$ for there to exist a unique (strong) solution to the SDE. There are lots of weaker conditions under which it holds, the most common being $b, \sigma$ globally Lipschitz.

Answer (score 1):

In the work ["Feynman-Kac Formulas for Solutions to Degenerate Elliptic and Parabolic Boundary-Value and Obstacle Problems with Dirichlet Boundary Conditions"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.03864.pdf) the authors develop a Feynman-Kac formulation in the case of weak regularity for the coefficients (including Hölder)

$$Au:=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}(a(x)D^{2}u(x))-\langle b(x),Du(x)\rangle+c(x)u(x)$$

and boundary data $g$, they obtain for the elliptic case $f=Au$

[image]

and the parabolic case $u_{t}=Au-f$

[image]